# How to format a button when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there some way to format a button in CSS so that is changes colour when clicked? I know that ':hover' can be used to change the colour but I was looking for something similar that related to a left mouse click.

I am after the general effect of a regular button but want to change the colour from the default blue.

Comment: Just while the button is down? Or do you want it to remain changed?

Comment: :active is What I needed. Sorry for the daftness...time to go to bed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you use the `:active` selector.
HTML:

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

CSS

```
button{
    background:green;
}
button:hover{
    background:lightgreen;
}
button:active{
    background:red;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterHappy/hZPWQ/)

Answer (score 2):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K46dh/)**

**Using `:active`**

This will apply CSS till mouse button is down & remove it once its up.

```
a:active{ //Your css for active state }
```

**Using `:focus`**

This will apply CSS once you press down mouse button and the style will remain there until user click/focus something else.

```
a:focus{ //Your css for focus state }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem with Javascript
**HTML**

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click me" onclick="changeColor();">
```

**Javascript**

```
changeColor = function(){
    document.getElementById("button").style.background='red';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYYcM/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css selector :active

```
button:active {
  background: red;
}
```

Checkout this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gomflo/43BuF/

Comment: Not a pseudo selector, those have the '::' (like ::after). That's just a regular selector.

Comment: I mean pseudo classes

Answer (score 0):

Use the :active CSS selector.

Example (makes the button have a 'click' effect):

```
.myButtonClass:active {
   position:relative;
   top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A buttons state becomes **active** once it's clicked. So you can use it like

```
.button1:active {
    color:#a2a2a2;
}
```